# Python tar extraction of a directory does not extract the directory's content

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python unzip a tar file does not unzip all the directory contents

I have a directory structure like this

```
'py'
'py/pran'
'py/typ'
'py/typ/tui'
'py/typ/tui/utopia'
'py/typ/tui/utopia/nuthsell'
'py/typ/tui/utopia/revy'
'py/typ/tui/utopia/bapy'


 import tarfile
 tar = tarfile.open('py.tar.gz','r:gz')
 memberList = []


for member in tar.getmembers():
   if member.name.endswith('utopia'):
        memberList.append(member)


tar.extractall(path='.',members=memberList)
```

After the extraction takes places I can only see the utopia folder but do not find the subfolders and content inside utopia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only extracted the utopia folder and not the subfolders since you check `member.name.endswith('utopia')`. Your subfolders do not end with 'utopia' and would not be appended to the `memberList`.
If your intention is to get all utopia folders, perhaps you want:

```
for member in tar.getmembers():
   if 'utopia' in member.name:
        memberList.append(member)
```

Comment: I had figured this out a while ago, but thanks for the quick answer